# Finished color of paint on two different woods

Tags: paint

If I use the same paint on both pine and maple wood will the color be the same or different?

Comment: It should be since you are going to prime first.  A single coat might not cover the difference completely, but a coat of primer and paint should.

Comment: If you're going to paint, why waste money on maple. Just use pine!

Comment: Probably following in the footsteps of the people who paint over black walnut and cherry woodwork & trim...if building something, why waste money on pine - use MDF if you're going to paint it.

Comment: WHAT IS IT?    You have a question and you aren't saying what you are painting.   Trim, cabinets, doors, other?

Answer (score 8):

Paint is opaque, so the color, if done correctly and with sufficient coats of primer and paint, should be identical on pine, maple, or particleboard.

Stain would be expected to look different as it is somewhat transparent.

Comment: Heavily disagree.    We don't know what he is painting but your answer isn't what I have experienced and I reuse and paint the crap out of everything I can.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer, then, @DMoore. In *my* experience if you get different color from the same paint on different substrates, you have a problem in your preparation and painting process.